# Reflectance Recognition with LIDAR Laser

Tags: lidar, object-recognition

I would like to know if anyone has tried to perform reflectance recognition using a Keyence SZ16D laser. I am attempting to guide my robot under a cabinet, which has metal legs. If I could detect the reflection from the cabinet's legs, I believe I could align the robot properly. My problem is that I don't know how to read the reflectance values from the laser. Would anyone have any ideas or suggestions?